# Postgresql Trigger for a Single Row Column Field

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I need some help in fixing my Postgres 9.4 Table Trigger configuration.  For the past couple of days I have been trying several different stackoverflow search ideas without success.  How can I fix my code to meet the simple requirements described below?

The requirement is to change the color field status based upon the current bus status field value.  The color update should only occur for the single row and NOT the entire BusColor table.  So when AI_Bus ‘1145’ operational status (BusStatus) is INSERT OR UPDATED, the trigger would change the color field to the proper associated color.  Say that the BusStatus for ‘1145’ is updated from ‘NSCH’ to ‘SCH’, then the trigger would change the color value from ‘white’ to ‘yellow’.  Below are my Posgresql 9.4 object configurations:

```
CREATE TABLE  BusColor (
AI_Bus      serial PRIMARY KEY,
BusStatus   character varying NOT NULL,
color       character varying NOT NULL );

SELECT * FROM “MyDB”.”BusColor”;
AI_Bus      BusStatus   color
1145        NSCH        white
1146        SCH         yellow
1147        NSCH        white
1148        OPER        green

CREATE TRIGGER “UpdateBusColor” BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON “BusColor”
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE “TrigFuncBusColor”();

CREATE FUNCTION “TrigFuncBusColor”() RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = ‘UPDATE’) THEN
    IF (NEW.”BusStatus” <> OLD.”BusStatus”) THEN
        IF NEW.“BusStatus” = ‘NSCH’ THEN
            UPDATE “MyDB”.”BusColor” SET “color” = ‘white’;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;

        IF NEW.“BusStatus” = ‘SCH’ THEN
            UPDATE “MyDB”.”BusColor” SET “color” = ‘yellow’;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;

         IF NEW.“ID_BusStatus” = ‘OPER’ THEN
            UPDATE “MyDB”.”BusColor” SET “color” = ‘green’;
            RETURN NEW;
         END IF;
   END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: You understand the trigger update wrong instead of using the `update set .... ` command you just set the value for the new field like `NEW.color = 'somevalue'`

Comment: I just tried using the UPDATE statement since the NEW & OLD were producing errors:  record "new" is not assigned yet.  The tuple structure is not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.  This is like version 50 for me...trying all of the crazy stuff on the Internet.

Comment: Change the trigger from `FOR EACH STATEMENT` to `FOR EACH ROW` and use the `NEW.field`

Comment: Thanks Jorge!  I switched back to `FOR EACH ROW` and changed the updates fields back to the original.   `CREATE TRIGGER “UpdateBusColor4” BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF “BusStatus”, color ON “BusColor” FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE “TrigFuncBusColor”();`

Comment: I also changed the trigger function:   `CREATE FUNCTION “TrigFuncBusColor”() RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 AS $$BEGIN
IF TG_OP = ‘UPDATE’ THEN
 IF (OLD.”BusStatus” <> NEW .”BusStatus”) THEN

  IF (NEW.“BusStatus” = ‘SCH’) THEN
   NEW.“color” = ‘yellow’;
   RETURN NEW;
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.“BusStatus” = ‘NSCH’) THEN
   NEW.“color” = ‘white’;
   RETURN NEW;
  END IF;

IF (NEW.“BusStatus” = ‘OPER’) THEN
  NEW.“color” = ‘green’;
  RETURN NEW;
 END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
`

Comment: Great that you could solve your problem. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why you use condition for each bus status, just select the color of replaced status and update the color of all which status is new one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION “TrigFuncBusColor”() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    declare newColor varchar;
    AS $$BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = ‘UPDATE’) THEN
        IF (NEW.”BusStatus” <> OLD.”BusStatus”) THEN
            SELECT "color" INTO newColor FROM “MyDB”.”BusColor” WHERE BusStatus = NEW.“BusStatus” LIMIT 1;
            UPDATE “MyDB”.”BusColor” SET “color” = newColor where BusStatus = NEW.“BusStatus”;
            RETURN NEW;
       END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
```